# Quadratic form inequality implies matrix inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Suppose we have the following quadratic form:

$$
x^T(t)(A^TP+PA)x(t)\le-x^T(t)Qx(t)\quad\forall t
$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are symmetric positive definite matrices and $\dot x(t)=Ax(t)$. Why does the above imply that:

$$
A^TP+PA\le -Q\,\,?
$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by $\forall t$? There is no $t$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry, I made an edit to fix that. The $t$ is on the $x$'s.

Comment: What is $x(t)$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese again made an edit, $x(t)$ is the solution to the ODE $\dot x(t)=Ax(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that $x(t)$ can take all values of the ambient space.

Note that the second inequality is simply the short usual way of saying that
$$
x^T(A^TP+PA)x\le-x^TQx
$$
for all $x$, and so what you are asking following directly from the definition.

Comment: Great, I see. This is what I thought.